# Concat fields in search plugin Cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Currently, I'm implementing the friendsofcake search plugin (version 1.2.3). Everything works as it should be with the exception that I want to concat two fields like this:

```
    $this->searchManager()
        ->add('id', 'Search.Value')
        ->add('q', 'Search.Like', [
            'before' => true,
            'after' => true,
            'field' => [$this->aliasField('username'), $this->aliasField('name')]
        ])
        ->add('q', 'Search.Callback', [
            'callback' => function ($query, $args, $manager) {
               return $query->select(['name' => $query->func()->concat(
                    ['first_name' => 'identifier', ' ' , 'last_name' => 'identifier']
                )]);
            }
        ]);
```

Since my database table stores first_name and last_name separate I want that the search plugin searches for these two fields combined (the name). The code above ignores the like clausule and when I print the query inside the callback it seems it ignores the like operation. Does anyone know how I can concat two fields within this search plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add multiple filters with the same name (`q`), the latter will overwrite the former, they won't get merged.

You'll have to build the conditions yourself in the callback too, ie add conditions for `username` and `name`. Also you have to use `HAVING` if you want to match using aggregated columns from the `SELECT` clause, or you have to build the aggregated column in the `WHERE` conditions too - depending on the DBMS that you are using, `WHERE` might be faster (though probably not when using `LIKE`, which makes using indices impossible, ie every single row will be touched anyways).

Here's a basic example using `HAVING`:

```
'callback' => function ($query, $args, $manager) {
    return $query
        ->select([
            $this->aliasField('username'),
            'name' => $query->func()->concat([
                'first_name' => 'identifier',
                ' ' ,
                'last_name' => 'identifier'
            ])
        ])
        ->having([
            'OR' => [
                $this->aliasField('username') . ' LIKE' => '%' . $args['q'] . '%',
                'name LIKE' => '%' . $args['q'] . '%'
            ]
        ]);
}
```

<sup>** untested example*</sup>

Comment: Since the data is actually interpolated into the result, this solution is not safe for SQL injection right?

Comment: @markvdlaan93 Not sure what you mean, the data is set separately as the value in a `key => value set`, and thus it is safe, as in conditions the right hand side value will alwas be subject to escaping unless they are expression objects (to be exact, the values are going to be set as bound parameters in a prepared query).

Comment: @markvdlaan93 You can check by debugging `$query->sql()` which will show the placeholders, and of course you could test it by trying to inject something :)